# Is it possible to use a ScatteringByteChannel based on an InputStream

Tags: java, nio

I want to split input data from a stream across multiple buffers.  I have explored NIO Channels, but cannot seem to find a way to do the equivalent of C's readv() on an InputStream.  Files, Sockets, etc all seem to have been covered, but not streams.
ScatteringByteChannel looks the most promising, but I have failed to set it up from an InputStream.
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for any tips.

- Chris

Answer (score 1):

Consider `nio` a rather low-level interface, as opposed to the high-level interface `java.io` provides. Your high-level stream might use *any* implementation. As long as you can read a byte at a time, you can turn it into a stream. The nio classes are for raw optimized operations on bulk data. To do that optimization, they have to know pretty well where their data comes from. And a generic `InputStream` simply doesn't fit into that image.

So although you could scatter the data from an input stream across multiple buffers, there is no optimized way to portably do so for every input stream. So you might as well implement this yourself, as `nio` won't provide any performance gain.

Notice that the `readv` C interface you refer to only accepts a low-level integer file handle, as opposed to the `FILE*` used by stdlib. The former can only denote a raw unbuffered kernel stream. The latter might denote anything (see `fopencookie` manpage), but won't provide raw optimized access.